# How to load data into text area of other website while loading

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to load some content into a text area on another website.

**Example:**

I have content stored in a variable or in a file (file.txt) and I have a website with a text area (for instance, www.google.com with search box)

After clicking the button on my html page I want to load the variable value into the text area while the website page starts loading.

Please help.

Comment: It would be easy to fill a text area from a javascript variable, but more complicated from a file, depending on if this file resides at the client (the computer of the person viewing the website) or the server. So what do you really want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin
I want compare two text contents which are in my variables using an external public website like http://jsondiff.com/
Now, i need to load my two variable contents to two text areas present in website

Comment: You can't just load the contents of a variable in a `textarea` of an external site. That's only possible if the external site gives you the means to do it. Otherwise it's impossible.